# Add an expander as an item in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a `ListView` into which I would like to insert a `Expander` control as an item (e.g in the third column). What function/method in `ListView` helps me do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ItemTemplate like this:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Expander Header="{Binding Title}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
      </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```